# Creating paragraphs in strings in cpp

Tags: c++, string

How to create new paragraph in the middle of a string text in cpp? For example crating a paragraph after "Name:"

```
int main() {
  std::cout << "Name: John";
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `\n` will add a newline to the string, so `std::cout << "Name:\nJohn";` may be more what you're looking for.

Comment: What character or encoding are you using to mark a paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [string escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) in C++. I assume you are looking for how to insert newlines: `\n`